# Is there anyway to test Athena integration in test containers

Tags: java, amazon-athena, testcontainers

I have a spring boot application and i want to test AWS Athena, I know that its possible to use local-stack (paid for).

https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/athena/

But i wanted to know is there an open source tool or is there a way i could test my service using test containers?

I have tried to find an alternative method of doing this testing, but have been unable to figure out a way.